# conflict between ontouchlistner and onlongclicklistner applied on same view in android

Tags: android

I have added `onLongclickListner` and `onTouchListner` to `LinearLayout`. In `onTouch()` function I have to return true because I have added `onGestureDetecter` inside the `ontouchListner` for capturing single and double taps. `onTouchListner` and `OnGestureListner` is working perfectly but `onLongclickListner` is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually `OnTouchListener` intercepts all touch events (also tap, click and etc). When `OnTouchListener` intercepts event he returns true on `onTouch()` method.

So you should return `false` in `onTouch()` in your appropriate circumstances. Then android framework is invoked `onLongClick`() in `OnLongClickListener`.

Or use `OnClickListener` instead `OnTouchListener`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the problem is I have to capture the motionEvent also. In onClickListner we will get only the view, we won't get motion event.

Comment: OK. In this case you should create all custom processing logic in onTouch() method